# select query - how to?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to execute this query. I'm using SQLiteDatabase. It works on the Database Browser but when I use it on Android Studio the cursor doesn't have data. What did I wrong?

```
  List<MoodListEntity> listData = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            DropTmpTable();
            String strQry = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEMP_TABLE(Emoji VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , Count int); INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE SELECT Emoji, COUNT (*) FROM Mood WHERE Date like '"+Date+"%' GROUP BY Emoji; SELECT * FROM TEMP_TABLE ORDER BY Count DESC LIMIT 5";
            Cursor cursor = super.rawQuery(strQry, null);

            if (cursor != null) {
                listData = microOrm.listFromCursor(cursor, MoodListEntity.class);
            }
        }catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return listData;
```

Comment: **1** - This is not a *query* but a *command*. **2** - SQLite doesn't execute multiple commands in one line.

Answer (score 0):

Separating SQL statements with `;` does not work with the sqlite APi - only the SQL up to the first `;` gets executed.

Instead split it to multiple `execSQL()` and `rawQuery()` calls.

Comment: Tks! It was really helpful for me.